# Lost internet after update

Tags: updates, internet

I am having a ptoblem with losr internet connectivity afert an update. I am getting the sysrem network service are not compatible with this version.

I have done the research and foumd the fix of downloading, transferring to the broken laptop and then using terminal to install the deb files. These are libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb libnl-genl-3_200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.c. they all install then I reboot and I still don't have internet.

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try to update again after the installation of the packages `apt-get update`

Comment: I did try to update agian but I have no internet connection so it failed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command to have a comprehensive output of the network state by typing

```
lspci -nn | egrep '0200|0280'
```

if it is something that looks like this :

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
```

Then remove this package

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and install instead

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

Disconnect the ethernet cable and then boot again and you should have your connection fixed.

Good luck

Comment: Hi interface I tried the command you suggested and i got 0e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200] and 14:00.0 Network controller [0820]. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes , actually that first command gives the state of Ethernet controller  as well as Network controller.
You can remove that package if nothing happens reinstall it again.

Comment: Ok  I just tried to remove bcmwl-kermel-source and it comes back with unable to locate that package

Comment: That means that it's not installed and the problem may have another cause.

Comment: Ok I thought that might be the case. I am going to reinstall the os again. It will be a pain but should work. Thank you so much for your help